# combination of numpy+scipy and cython

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, cython

I am trying to write a function to calculate the correlation matrix of a NumPy array with for loops and the `pearsonr` and the `spearmanr` functions from SciPy to calculate the matrix (I know that pandas do the same!!!).
I am trying to use Cython to improve the performance of the function, as its current speed is not even comparable to its pandas equivalent (`pd.corr()`). I am not even sure if this is the way to do it, so, feel free to suggest anything.
here is te code for .pyx and setup.py and also for the performance evaluation with three functions: `pandas corr()`, one `custom corr function` in python, and the same function in `cython` with types.

main.pyx

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
cimport numpy as np


np.import_array()


DTYPE = np.float64


ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t


def cor_custom_c(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x):
    cdef int dim = x.shape[1]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] mat = np.ones([dim, dim], dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef int i, j
    cdef double pv
    x = x.T
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if i <= j:
                continue
            else:
                pv = pearsonr(x[i], x[j])[0]
            mat[i, j] = pv
            mat[j, i] = pv
    return mat
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(name='Main',
      ext_modules=cythonize([Extension("main", ["main.pyx"], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])])
)
```

check.py

```
import time
import main
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import pandas as pd


def cor_custom(x):
    mat = np.ones((x.shape[1], x.shape[1]))
    dim = x.shape[1]
    x = x.T
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if i <= j:
                continue
            else:
                pv = pearsonr(x[i], x[j])[0]
            mat[i, j] = pv
            mat[j, i] = pv
    return mat


data = {}
sample_size = 100
n_feature = 100
print('Sample size: ', sample_size)
print('Number of Features: ', n_feature)
for i in range(n_feature):
    data['col_'+str(i)] = np.random.randint(0, 10, sample_size)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

xx = df.to_numpy(dtype=np.float64, na_value=np.nan, copy=False)
st = time.time()
pd_cr = df.corr(method='pearson')
print('pandas: ', "----%.5f----" % (time.time()-st))

st = time.time()
num_cr = cor_custom(x=xx)
print('numpy only: ', "----%.5f----" % (time.time()-st))

st = time.time()
cython_cr = main.cor_custom_c(xx)
print('cython: ', "----%.5f----" % (time.time()-st))

print('Check pandas corr() equal to cython corr(): ', all(cython_cr == pd_cr))

print('numpy+scipy+cython: ', "----%.5f----" % (time.time()-st))
```

The performance is as follows:

- Sample size:  100
- Number of Features:  100
- pandas: ----0.00282----
- numpy only:  ----0.32579----
- numpy+scipy+cython:  ----0.32199----

Comment: I suspect most of the work is in the Scipy `pearsonr` function. Cython can't magically reach inside it and speed it up so this probably isn't a useful way to proceed.

Comment: I checked the pandas source code and it's using the Scipy functions and it is super fast. do you have any suggestions for me on how to proceed? Is there a way to speed-up scipy?

Comment: No I don't think Pandas is using Scipy for dataframes. I think it's using its own Cython code for dataframes https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6dc589b957e494750351e8572b45b8fa12c27d01/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx#L322